# In eclipse after run its doesn't show anything in consol

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;

    printf("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Your number is %d",a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you try this? system("pause"); return 0;

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly are you doing, what actually happens and what would you expect to happen? For me, the program works as expected.

Comment: i am just start to coding in eclipse, what i did means i just type this example code but unfortunately after i run this its doesn't show any thing in console but actually result should be in enter a number but its not coming any thing , but  if i enter anything the question and result coming same time